# How to add updated information to one table to another with previous information

Tags: sql

I have two tables first one master's table second one customers table.in customers table updated information will be stored ,how to add updated information to the first table including previous information.so how to add updated information to the master's table.

Comment: Maybe use a database trigger?

Comment: Use `MERGE` statement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

you could create a stored procedure to execute both the queries like this. Syntax might be incorrect so check for your self and google about stored procedures.

```
create procedure updatecustomer
@customerid int,
@customercolumn data_type
as
update customer set customercolumn = @customercolumn where customerid = @customerid
insert into admin(customerid, customercolumn) values(@customerid, @customercolumn)
```

Comment: Why not a trigger instead?

Comment: I didn't think of it at first, although that is more efficient way i think.

Comment: I'm using hive so when I create store procedure it doesn't work

Comment: I guess the only option remains is firing both the queries based on successful result of first one you could do something like if query 1 is success then fire query 2